# Estimating the hitting time for a SDE solution

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a the following OU process in one dimension,
$$dX = -\theta(X -x_0)dt + \sqrt{s}dW $$

Now one can define the time $t_x$ as the time it takes for the solution to reach the point $x$.

Then apparently the following estimate holds,

- $$\mathbb E [ t_x] \sim \sqrt{\frac{\pi s}{\theta}} \cdot \frac{e^{\frac{\theta(x-x_0^2)}{s}}}{\theta (x- x_0)}  $$

  Can someone kindly reference me a derivation of this?
- In the above the point $x$ is not special in anyway from the point of view of the SDE. But suppose I construct the following possibly more interesting situation :

  Consider a function $f(x) = \frac{\theta}{2} \cdot (x - x_0)^2 + g(x)$ and suppose $x_* = {\rm argmin} f(x)$. Now we consider the SDE, $dX = -(\theta(X -x_0) + g'(X))dt + \sqrt{s}dW $ Now can similar estimates be made for $\mathbb{E}[ t_{x_*}]$ ? ( making whatever might be convenient assumptions on $g$ except to set it to a constant) If necessary we can assume that $x_0$ is a critical point or a non-trivial local minima of $f$

Comment: Estimate as what goes to what? I assume it's as $x$ goes to infinity, but in that case I'm not sure how to make sense of your second question. For the first, I would for convenience find $a$ and $b$ such that $Y_t=a(X_{by}-x_0)$ satisfies $dY_t=-Y_tdt+dB'_t$.

Comment: Then you can play with the fact that $F(Y_t)^2-t$ is a martingale for $F(y)=\int_0^y\exp(w^2)dw$, as well as the explicit representation of $Y_t$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for such a calculation? I couldnt find anything like this estimation done anywhere!

Comment: I don't. I'm not even saying I could do the exercise, I'm just throwing ideas.

Comment: What is the initial condition of $X(t)$?

Comment: $X(0) = x_0$ suppose

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the expected hitting time estimate, there are many references eg. ["The estimates of the mean first exit time from a ball for the α-stable Ornstein–Uhlenbeck processes"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414907000336) equation 5.35

$$c^{-1}\frac{e^{\lambda r^{2}}}{r^{d}}\leq E_{0}(\tau_{B_{0}(r)})\leq c\frac{e^{\lambda r^{2}}}{r^{d}},$$

, ["Exit times and Poisson kernels of the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/15326340802009337)", ["First-Passage-Time Density and Moments of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/3214232.pdf) and in this [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866723/expected-hitting-time-of-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process) too.

In terms of the other process, if you have any comparison results between the two drifts $b_{1}:=-\theta(x-x_0)$ and $b_{2}(x):=-\theta(x-x_0)+g'(x)$ then you could try using a comparison theorem for their solutions $X_{b_{1}},X_{b_{2}}$ such as the one by Nakao ["On pathwise uniqueness and comparison of solutions of one-dimensional stochastic differential equations"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-20/issue-1/On-pathwise-uniqueness-and-comparison-of-solutions-of-one-dimensional/ojm/1200775827.full)

[image]